# Ezekiel 44:21 NIV vs BSB, when vs before

Tags: ezekiel

Ezekiel 44:21
New International Version

> No priest is to drink wine **when** he enters the inner court.

Berean Study Bible

> No priest may drink wine **before** he enters the inner court.

Can a priest drink wine after he enters the inner court?

Answer (score 2):

The verb in question is
בְּבֹואָ֖ם - prep. + Qal inf. cons. + 3rd person, masc. pl. suffix.
like the Greek participle, when time is involved, this can be translated *when, before, or after* depending on the context.  Most likely the idea is immediately before (while still under the influence) and during.  Note: *when entering* does have the sense of immediately before being in the inner court.   Searching Bibles for *wine AMD "inner court"* only finds Ezekiel 44>21.  So there is no other passage in the Tanakh for additional information.

> Followed by an inf. בְּ forms a periphrasis for the gerund, as בִּשְׁתֹק in ridendo, Pro. 14:13, and is commonly expressed by conjunctions, namely—(a) while, when (in that, comp. A, 1 used of time), Num. 35:19. בְּפִטגְעוֹ “when he lighteth upon him.” Pro. 30:32; Cant. 5:6; Est. 2:8.—(b) when, after that (comp. A, 3 of completed time), followed by a pluperf. where the infinitive has the power of a preterite; Gen. 33:18, בְּבֹאוֹ מִפַּדַּן אֲרָם “when he had come out of Mesopotamia;” 2:4; Ex. 3:12; Isa. 20:1; Job. 42:10. —-
> Gesenius, W., & Tregelles, S. P. (2003). Gesenius’ Hebrew and Chaldee lexicon to the Old Testament Scriptures (p. 99). Bellingham, WA: Logos Bible Software.

> 21No priest shall drink wine when he enters into the inner court.
> --
> Jewish Publication Society. (1985). Tanakh: The Holy Scriptures (Ezekiel 44:21). Philadelphia: Jewish Publication Society.